# Batch file rename output folder

Tags: batch-file

So I have the following code to overlay a logo image over some videos. Its working great, the only problem I have is since my logo has the naming like "0001.logo.png", the output rar file doesnt set the right file extension, it sets the "myFolder_0001.logo" extension. Is it possible to remove the '0001.' part of the name of the logo when I am naming the rar/folder?

Thank you so much for your help.

```
@echo off
setlocal 
EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FolderBaseName=myFolder"

set "DropBoxFolder=C:\Users\admin\Desktop\tests\automate\sync"

set "BaseOutputFolder=%TEMP%\%FolderBaseName%"


for %%I in (*.png) do (

    set "OutputFolder=%BaseOutputFolder%_%%~nI"

    md "!OutputFolder!" 2>nul

    for %%J in (*.mp4*) do (

        ffmpeg -i "%%~fJ" -i "%%~fI" -filter_complex overlay "!OutputFolder!\%%~nJ.mp4"

    )


    "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 "%DropBoxFolder%\%FolderBaseName%_%%~nI" "!OutputFolder!\*"

    rd /S /Q "!OutputFolder!"


)


pause
```

Comment: Is your problem that it's dropping the `.png` or that it's not dropping the `_0001`?

Comment: not dropping the '0001.', the png is ok with %%~nI, since i dont want the extension in the name of the folder. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). For instance, to replace all `.` full stops with a minus sign (dash?) `-`, use

```
set "slaveName=%%~nI"
set "slaveName=!slaveName:.=-!
set "OutputFolder=%BaseOutputFolder%_!slaveName!"
```